# How to post boolean value using volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to post boolean value using volley library.When a button is clicked,a boolean value is set to true.The boolean value is then posted to my php script to increment counter in my mysql database. i am getting an error in trying to add a request to queue. What am i doing wrong? This is my code

```
        holder.custom_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int count;


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                count = 0;

                superHeroes.get(position).setCount(superHeroes.get(position).getCount() + 1);
                holder.txtCount.setText(superHeroes.get(position).getCount() + "");


                final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/likes.php";

                isLiked = true;

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    obj.put("isLiked", true);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest

                        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
// i am getting error here
                customVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

            }


        });
```

SINGLETON

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.myfeed;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
/**
 * Created by Belal on 12/5/2015.
 */

public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

ERROR

```
'getInstance(android.content.Context)' in 'net.simplifiedcoding.myfeed.CustomVolleyRequest' cannot be applied to '(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)'
```

Comment: Have you created the singleton class for volley?

Comment: Boolean thing is right, You must be missing the Singleton class of volley.

Comment: You should use `POST` instead of `GET`, like the following `JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {...`

Comment: It would be nice if you could post stack trace of the error that you are getting.

Comment: ERROR 'getInstance(android.content.Context)' in 'net.simplifiedcoding.myfeed.CustomVolleyRequest' cannot be applied to '(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)'

Comment: In this line: customVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest); - "this" - is not context! This is reference of ClickListener.

Comment: Change this line to: customVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

Comment: Now I'm getting the ERROR Cannot resolve method 'addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest)' @SergeyNeskoromny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **not** making `POST` request. You should do like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, url,
      new JSONObject(jsonParams),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // Handle response
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              //   Handle Error
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }
};
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req); // AppController is Volley Singleton.
```

You have used `CardAdapter`, I don't what that is. You should always add the request object to `Volley Singleton`. [Reference](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/).

Comment: What should i use in place of "content-type" and "application/json; charset=utf-8" ? @RohitArya

Comment: Since you are making a json object request, you should use the same. But it totally depends on your backend implementation.